# Counting distinct values for multiple months

Tags: mysql

Got a little problem here. I can't for the life of me, figure out how to do this.

```
pid | firstlast | lastvisit | zip 
---------------------------------------
435 | 2001-01-17 | 2012-01-21 | 46530
567 | 2001-01-18 | 2012-01-21 | 46530
532 | 2001-01-19 | 2012-01-22 | 46535
536 | 2001-01-19 | 2012-01-23 | 46535
539 | 2001-01-20 | 2012-01-27 | 46521
```

Here is my SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT zip, COUNT(zip) AS totalzip FROM production WHERE MONTH(lastvisit) = "1" GROUP BY zip ORDER BY totalzip DESC;
```

Output:

Jan:

```
zip | totalzip
--------------------- 
46530 | 2
46535 | 2
46521 | 1
```

Feb:

```
zip | totalzip
--------------------- 
46530 | 1
46521 | 4
49112 | 3
```

This is great for the 1st month, but I need this for the entire year. I could run this query 12 times, however 2 problems occur. I have over 300 zip codes for the entire year. On some months the zip code is not present, so the count is 0 (but the MySQL output doesn't output the "zero data". Also, when I order by totalzip, the order changes from month to month, and this does not allow me to paste them into a spread sheet. I can order by zip code, but again the "zero" data zipcodes are not present and so the list changes from month to month.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I was able to get a little farther using some of your idea's. I am still having a problem getting nicely formatted data though.



SELECT * FROM production
INNER JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT zip, COUNT( zip ) AS Jan FROM production WHERE MONTH(lastvisit) = "1" GROUP BY zip) AS JanCount
ON
(production.zip = JanCount.zip)

INNER JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT zip, COUNT( zip ) AS Feb FROM production WHERE MONTH(lastvisit) = "2" GROUP BY zip) AS FebCount
ON
(production.zip = FebCount.zip)

But I get repeated records.

Comment: I'm just a basic mysql user so I am not exactly sure how these joins work and why the data is repeating.

What I need is the row to look like this:

46516 : 71 | 45 | 32 | 45 | 12 | 66 | 55 | 32 | 22 | 66 |71 | 12

(each number representing the count for a month (Jan-Dec)

Comment: check my answer... that will give you what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this work with subqueries:

```
select 
    a.*, count(c.zip) as totalZip
from
   (select 
       monthVisit, zip
    from
        (select distinct last_day(lastVisit) as monthVisit from production) as m,
        (select distinct zip from production) as z
   ) as a
   left join (select 
                  last_day(lastVisit) as monthVisit, zip
              from production) as c
       on a.monthVisit=c.monthVisit and a.zip=c.zip
 group by
     a.monthVisit, a.zip
```

This should give you the count of zips for each month you have, including zeros.

Let me explain how this works:

First, I defined a subquery that makes *all* the possible combinations of zips and months (the `a` subquery), and then I left joined this with a second subquery that returns the values of ZIPs and months (the `c` subquery). Using `left join` allows to count the possible empty combinations in the `a` subquery.

Hope this help you.

Note: The `last_day()` function returns the last day of the month of a given date; e.g.: `last_day('2012-07-17')='2012-07-31'`

Comment: Just a comment: this works only if your table is not large, since the `last_day()` function has to be evaluated for each record. But, since you are already grouping the data using the `month()` function, this may be just what you need.

Comment: There has to be something wrong with your query. All the zips on any month return only "0" or "1" visit. Some of these zips should have close to a hundred visits.

Comment: @user1532528 well, you're right! sorry, I assumed you wanted a count of unique zips... Check again the answer, I've edited the query (just remove the `distinct` in query `c`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a zipcode table (you should), you could join it with your data table (a left join), which would bring even the zero-count zipcodes.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your question is solved with additional grouping. Try something like this:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT zip, YEAR(lastvisit),  MONTH(lastvisit), COUNT(zip) AS totalzip 
 FROM production 
 GROUP BY  zip, YEAR(lastvisit),  MONTH(lastvisit)
 ORDER BY totalzip DESC;
```

To add in the "zero" summaries when no data is present I typically do a left-join with a complete list. (This is also stated by @Alfabravo above). So the final query looks a bit like:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT zip, YEAR(lastvisit),  MONTH(lastvisit), COUNT(zip) AS totalzip 
 FROM production left join 
      (SELECT DISTINCT zip from production) as zipMap on zipmap.zip = production.zip
 GROUP BY  zip, YEAR(lastvisit),  MONTH(lastvisit)
 ORDER BY totalzip DESC;
```